# Unable to Modify Shared Advanced Find View

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am a system admin. I have created an Advanced Find query and shared it to someone in my organization. I gave them access to share, modify, delete, etc. on that saved query. They are able to access the saved query. However when they modify the query, they are unable to save it. They have the 'read' access on Customization. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Pls make sure the users are having privilege to update the saved view entity. [Read more](https://blog.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/harshaniperera/2019/04/09/how-to-create--share--delete-and-set-a-personal-view-to-default-in-microsoft-dynamics-365)

[image]

Comment: Arun, thank you for your reply. The user actually already has the Saved View and View access.

Comment: @ichachan so button disabled or error while saving? Can you update the question clearly with screenshot without sensitive data.